# What are the differences between "there" & "in there".?

Tags: word-usage

I couldn't find any source on the internet that explains the differences between "**there**" & "**in there**".

It seems that "**there**" emphasizes locations in general & "**in there**" emphasizes the inside of something.

Ex1: *Don't go in there. It's too cold.*

Ex2: *Don't Go There! (a travel guiding book says that)*

It would be great if you showed me a reliable source that mentioned this.

Comment: Your second sentence accurately summarises the significance of including ***in***. What don't you understand?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I need a referencing source. I am not a native & my students won't believe me if my sayings have no reference. Could you give me a referencing source?

Comment: Exactly as you said.
_In there_ emphasizes the position of some place. _There_ is the general definition, it may be _on_, _in_, _at_, _inside_.. 

_Don't go on there! There have been people who claimed to have seen ghosts!_

Comment: @Tom: Suspicious lot, your students! If you manage to convince them of the difference with ***in***, will they demand similar "reliable sources" for every one of the different prepositions (and the different *verbs* that might precede them)? I think the scope of the question might be too broad for this kind of site.

Comment: Don't go on there? What, the roof or jungle jim?? /In there/ means an enclosed space or area. The enclosure can be a building or it can be a fence around an area, for instance. But as a teacher, I would have thought this is obvious. Because the idea of in and in there exists in most languages....

Comment: Whoops: I meant to write on Jan 8, in and on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**In there**" mostly refers to the inside of a specific location, object, building - something somebody or something enters, penetrates, infiltrates or visits.

- That's a cryochamber, **don't go in there**! It's too cold. = *Don't go inside the cryochamber because it is cold inside.*

"**There**" refers to a place, location, building, object - something in general.

- If you've never been in Antarctica, **don't go there**. It's too cold. = *Don't go to the place called Antarctica because it is cold there.*

Practically, different prepositions can be used with "**there**" and "**here**" like "**in**", "**on**", "**over**", "**up**", "**down**", e.t.c.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing what is grammatically known as a "preposition", a word governing, and usually preceding, a noun or pronoun and expressing a relation to another word or element.  And yes "in there" is specific to a location.

[The Preposition](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/preposition.htm)

Comment: Here or there are adverbs & generally, they don't need a proposition before them.

Answer (score 0):

You usually use the word there as an adverb, but it can be used as a noun/pronoun.

When you say "Don't go there", you are using the there as an adverb meaning "to that place". So Don't go there = Don't go to that place.

As a noun, the there means "that place". The preposition "in" means inside. So Don't go in there = Don't go inside that place.